# Does the previous (Javascript) local-storage data will be persisted when Windows 10 UWP apps gets updated

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10, local-storage, xbox-one

We are developing a Windows UWP Javascript app for XBOX and we are storing user data in the localStorage web api.

Does the localStorage persist the data when there is an app update.

Thank You,
Harshin

Answer (score 0):

> Does the localStorage persist the data when there is an app update.

Local: stored on the device, backed up in the cloud, and persists across updates.

For more detail you could refer to [ApplicationData Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalCacheFolder).